could not able to load the index.html page with Spring boot thymeleaf application?
i'm facing 404 Error when i deploy Spring and thymeleaf project into tomcat
Error

I need to able to get load the index page when I start the application
in Spring boot application webApp is not present so, I used static and template to write the html pages.
index.html page is present under template folder

paste controller, pom.xml and properties file , how does anybody can answer with only image ?

Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question to add more details of your problem.

@Controller
public class HomeController {
@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

} this is the controller
